# PHP: Destroying Object after reloading the page

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

```
<?php $mView = new systemModuleView();?>
<?php $mView->nextPage(); ?>
<?= $mView->showTable()["table"]; ?>
```

I have this View Class to get some content out of my table. That works so far. But I want to call the method: nextPage after clicking a specific button. The page must not reload because this will destroy the Object...

I have tried several things:

Session

Ajax

But that doesn't work.

Comment: The object is already destroyed once your page is loaded.. You don't have anything left, unless you save it in a cooki or a session..

Comment: When you say you have 'tried' Ajax, what do you mean? If you don't want to reload the page, then you have to use JavaScript make some kind of XML Http Request to your PHP server, which is essentially what Ajax is. Can you show the code for what you tried? As a quick solution, try using jQuery's `load()` function, with a GET variable appended for the page number you want. Change the page number every time someone clicks the request button.

Comment: If you are trying to keep elements on your page after page load and then load new content as well without reloading the current page, that is AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest json encoding your object and then putting it in a session.
Then if you want to get your object again just read the sesion and json_decode it.

Comment: i will try that in a few minutes